# Why did "argument can be squished against option" prevail over "argument is always separate"?

Tags: history, options

Inspired by the recent question [Why does the specific sequence of options matter for tar command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187756/41515), in which the asker learned why `tar -cfv test.tar *.jpg` doesn't work, I'd like to ask a followup: seriously, why not?

When a command has an option `-f` that requires an argument and an option `-v` that doesn't, this:

```
cmd -fv foo
```

can be interpreted in 2 different ways: the `v` is the argument for the `-f` option and `foo` is a non-option argument, or `foo` is the argument for the `-f` option and the `-v` option is present. The first interpretation is what POSIX `getopt()` does, so there are lots of commands that behave that way.

I always preferred the second interpretation. Packing all the options together (regardless of whether they take arguments) seems more useful than squishing the `foo` up against the `-f` to turn `-f foo` into `-ffoo`. But this behavior barely exists anymore. The only command I've used lately that does it is Java's `jar` (which has a syntax clearly inspired by that Sun version of `tar` which accepts `tar cfv tarfile ...`).

Xlib has a `getopt`-like function, `XrmParseCommand`, which allows options to be specified as either taking "separate" args or "sticky" args. But it deals with long options (`-display`, `-geometry`, etc.) so it sees `-fv` as just another option with no relation to either `-f` or `-v`. So it's not an example of my second interpretation.

When and why did squished args become dominant? Was it already settled before POSIX, or did the POSIX mandate decide the issue? Did the first version of POSIX even have the same specific requirement as the current version? Is there any archived discussion of the subject from ancient times?

Are there any other commands (besides `tar` and `jar`) that support or have historically supported the `-fv foo` = `-f foo -v` style of option parsing?

Comment: Argument squishing was prevalent before POSIX. In fact, AT&T's Unix Labs had proposed a flag and option syntax that `getopt()` had pretty faithfully implemented by 1988. I can't really cite any docs, but that's when I got my first real Unix(tm) machine, and there was a manual section on the subject.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, in standard `getopt()`-style argument processing, arguments don't have to be squished against the option they apply to, they just can be. So if `-f` takes an argument, both of the following are valid:

```
command -ffoo positional arguments
command -f foo positional arguments
```

What you call the "second interpretation" is in fact very, very rare. As far as I can think of right now, `tar` and `mt` are the only extant commands that works that way... and, as you mention, `jar`, but that's only because it emulates `tar`. These commands process arguments very differently from the standard `getopt()`-style. The options are not even preceeded by `-`! I can't say for sure why it was rarely used, but I would guess that it's because of the fact that it's harder to tell what options go with what arguments. For example, if `b` and `d` take arguments but `a`, `c`, and `e` don't, then you have this:

```
command abcde b-argument d-argument
```

...which means that while you are composing the command you have to look back at the option letter group, read it again, remember which options you specified require arguments, and write out the arguments in the same order. What about this?

```
command adcbe b-argument d-argument
```

Oops, the `d` option got the `b-argument` and vice versa. Worse, if you see:

```
command lmnop foo bar baz
```

...and you are not familiar with the command, you have no idea which arguments go with which options. `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` might be arguments to `n`, `o`, `p` (and `l` and `m` take no arguments) or `foo` and `bar` might go with, say `m` and `p` while `baz` is a positional parameter... or many other possible combinations.